# How do i create a simple Javascript Program that displays the value of <input type="text">?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, and i only know c++ so far, but i know the logic but i just don't know the syntax on javascript

so i have this form :

```
<span>Please type your name here: </span>
<input id="inputname" type="text" value=""></input>
```

when the user types his/her name how do i save the value to some variable and display it with javascript?

i have already tried using

```
function displayName(){
    var username = getElementById("inputname").value;
    document.write(username);
}
```

and i put

```
<script>displayName();</script>
```

below the form. it doesn't seem to work, how do i do it?

and how do i use:

```
<input type="submit"></input>
```

in relation to it?

Comment: change this line getElementById("inputname").value; to document.getElementById("inputname").value; and you should be through

Comment: When exactly you want to show the value of text on page? when you submit the button or while typing in the textbox?

Comment: It'd have been better if you read some tutorial sites rather than posting in SO..

Comment: @RashminJaviya when i hit the submit button, i want it to appear beside or under the forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**Javascript**

```
function displayName(){
    var username = document.getElementById("inputname").value;
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = username;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span>Please type your name here: </span>
<input id="inputname" type="text" value=""></input>

<input type="button" onclick="displayName();"></input>
<span id="msg"></span>
```

By changing `onclick="return displayName()"` to `onkeypress="displayName()"` you will be able to see the changes on the spot.

Comment: You won't be needing that return statement since it's not a `submit` button and nothing is inside a form.

Comment: @TilwinJoy hey, sorry for asking questions like this :( and glad you still correct the syntax that people put here, thanks so much, i'm sorry again

Comment: @RashminJaviya thanks! i put onkeypress="displayName()" inside the input text form and it works :D

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your fucntion little bit..

getElementById() is not a direct function in javascript..use it with document object

```
 function displayName(){
        var username = document.getElementById("inputname").value;
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = username;
return false;
    }
```

on submit click

```
 <input type="submit" id="btnSave" onclick="return displayName();" value="Save" />

<div id="msg" > </div>
```

Comment: thanks! say how do i use <input type"submit"></submit> to display what the user has typed?

Comment: there are many ways to do it..but you can simply do it by using <input type="submit" id="btnSave" onclick="display();" value="Save" />

Comment: alright i did it, but my problem now is when i hit submit button it makes the textbox and the submit button disappear and only displays the value, how do i make it stay?

Comment: @Twish please go read some tutorials and learn javascript. You don't seem to have a specific problem that needs answering.

Comment: just change ... onclick="display(); return false;"

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal it won't work. read more about `document.write`. please don't encourage such behaviour. the OP can solve his problems one by one simply by searching. these were already answered too many times. This shows no effort from OP's side. SO is not running tutorials...

Answer (score 0):

change your html and js like this. `onblur` function call when user leaves the input from focus. get the enter value `onblur`

```
<span>Please type your name here: </span>
<input id="inputname" type="text" onblur="displayName();" value=""></input>
```

**js**

```
function displayName(){
    var username = document.getElementById("inputname").value;
    document.write(username);
}
```